# Double and triple angle formulas for sin and cos

Tags: trigonometry

A friend asked me to help him with a trig equation, but I got stuck and can't really come up with the answer. I am not asking you to solve the equation, but just to point out any errors that I did and to give me some advice on how to proceed.

The equations is the one below :

$\cos 3x + \sin 2x - \sin 4x = 0$

This is what I came up with :

$ 4\cos^3x - 3\cos x + 2\cos x\sin x - 2\cos 2x\sin 2x = 0$

$4\cos^3x(1 - \sin x) - 3\cos x + 2\cos x\sin x = 0$

$\cos x(4(1-\sin x)\cos^2x - (3 - 2\sin x)) = 0$

Here comes the first error :

$\cos x=0$

so

$ x = 0\pi$ or $x = \frac{3\pi}{2}$

but when I substitute these values in the original equation I don't get $0$ :(

When I try to solve the rest of the equation, I get $$\cos x = \frac{\pm 2\sqrt{(\sin x - 1)(\sin x - \frac{3}{2})}}{4(1-\sin x)}$$

But given the first error, I don't think that this is the solution.

Comment: Yeah, thank you! I wrote cos4x by mistake, its actually cos3x

Comment: $-2\cos(2x)\sin(2x)=-2(2\cos^2(x)-1)\cdot 2\cos(x)\sin(x)=-8\sin(x)\cos^3(x)+4\sin(x)\cos(x)$.

Comment: To obtain $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, and $\cot x$, type \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, and \cot x, respectively, when you are in math mode.  Note that if $\cos x = 0$, then the terminal side of angle $x$ lies on the $y$-axis, so $x = \frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It seems that you get $-2\cos(2x)\sin(2x)=-4\cos^3(x)\sin(x)$ where you have an error. See my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier this way:
$$\begin{aligned}0&=\cos 3x +\sin 2x-\sin4x\\
&= \cos 3x +2\sin\left(\frac{2x-4x}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{2x+4x}{2}\right)\\
&=2\left(\frac12-\sin x\right)\cos3x.
\end{aligned}$$